# ¿Encontrar diferencias en dos tablas SQL?

Tags: sql-server

Buen día.
Esperando me puedan ayudar, he buscados por Google pero sin encontrar lo que necesito, y no se si se pueda hacer o no.
Cuento con una tablas en una base y en otra base esta la misma tabla, estas están en servidores diferentes, las tengo unidas por linked server.
Lo que requiero es poder encontrar las diferencias entre ambas, es decir si un campo existe en una tabla que me muestre si es diferente y si no existe, pues muestre el campo.
La tabla seria más o menos asi:

```
        Tabla1
Id        Cons         valor1      
1              1          spAltaCliente2

Tabla2
Id        Cons         valor1        
1              1           spAltaCliente
```

Y el resultado que espero es este:

```
        Tabla1
Id        Cons         valor1      
1              1          spAltaCliente2
```

He intentado con distinct y join, pero no es resultado que busco.
De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: `valor1` es lo único que puede ser diferente? si encuentra diferencias entre ambas, siempre debe devolver lo que tenga `Tabla1`?

Comment: Agradezco la respuesta @L. Ronquillo, así es, la diferencia siempre estará en valor1, y si encuentra diferente deberá mandar el valor distinto de Tabla2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estoy seguro de haber entendido bien el problema.

Lo que puedes hacer para buscar diferencias entre dos columnas de distintas tablas es hacer un INNER JOIN para vincular los registros de ambas tablas y usar CASE para detectar si el valor de ambos columnas coincide o no.

Puedes hacer una query como la siguiente, si t1.valor1 = t2.valor1 muestra t1.valor1 y sino coinciden muestra 'ES DIFERENTE!' (Tu decides que mostrar en cada caso).

Asumo que Id es la primary key en ambas tablas (la utilizo para vincular), y que el tipo de la columna valor1 es de algún tipo string (varchar, text, etc).

```
SELECT 
    t1.Id,
    t1.Cons,
    CASE WHEN t1.valor1 = t2.valor1 THEN t1.valor1 ELSE 'ES DIFERENTE!' END AS valor1
FROM Tabla1 AS t1
INNER JOIN Tabla2 AS t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id;
```

Si quieres seleccionar solo los registros en los cuales ambas columnas tienen el mismo valor (o cuyos valores no coinciden) puedes utilizar la claúsula WHERE (`WHERE t1.valor1 = t2.valor1` o `WHERE t1.valor1 != t2.valor1`).

Comment: Tal vez sea bueno incluir `t1.valor` y `t2.valor`  en la proyección para ver los valores directamente, en lugar de hacer una consulta más por los Id's

Comment: Hola @Arriel, armé la query según lo que interpreté de los requerimientos de Geovani, obviamente cada uno la puede modificar de acuerdo a los datos que necesite. Mi query es mas bien orientativa, es una forma de obtener lo que creo que necesita.

Comment: Hola @nachospiu, agradezco la respuesta, lo reviso, y te explico lo que se intento hacer y como lo tengo. Actualmente tengo dos servidores en red, cada uno tiene una BD con la misma estructura en cuanto a tablas, y lo que intento buscar en una tabla de ambas BD, que datos son diferentes, por ejemplo, en Tabla 1 de BD1, existen registros que también están en Tabla1 de BD2, pero son diferentes en el campo valor1.

Comment: Hola @Geovani, bien, entonces podrías agregar la claúsla `WHERE t1.valor1 != t2.valor1`, y seleccionar t1.valor1 y t2.valor2 (en el SELECT) como decía @Arriel para ver las diferencias (en lugar del CASE). Las otras respuestas también te pueden servir.

Answer (score 3):

Para casos como este utilizo el operador de conjuntos [`EXCEPT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

La consulta sería la siguiente:

```
SELECT Id, Cons, valor1 FROM Tabla1 EXCEPT
SELECT Id, Cons, valor1 FROM Tabla2
```

Esta consulta devolverá todo lo que esté en `tabla1` que tenga diferencias o que no exista en `tabla2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.*
from tabla1 t1
where t1.valor not in
(select t2.valor
 from tabla2 t2
)
```

Se realiza una **subconsulta** dentro de la **cláusula where** del primer **select** y utilizando el **operador not in** se muestran los campos que no están en el resultado que devuelve la **subconsulta**.